# Magento error writing to file when logged into the admin section

Tags: php, magento

I am running Magento on my Vagrant box (running Centos) - when I login to my backend admin I get the following error message - can anyone assist?

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3 Error writing file '/tmp/MYgGnO2P' (Errcode: 28)

Trace:
#0 /vagrant/www.mysite.com/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /vagrant/www.mysite.com/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /vagrant/www.mysite.com/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /vagrant/www.mysite.com/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT DISTINCT...', Array)
#4 /vagrant/www.mysite.com/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT DISTINCT...', Array)
#5 /vagrant/www.mysite.com/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(734): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT DISTINCT...', Array)
#6 /vagrant/www.mysite.com/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(734): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('SELECT DISTINCT...', Array)
#7 /vagrant/www.mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(521): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_fetchAll('SELECT DISTINCT...', Array)
#8 /vagrant/www.mysite.com/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(566): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->getData()
#9 /vagrant/www.mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(533): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
#10 /vagrant/www.mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Searches/Top.php(68): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#11 /vagrant/www.mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(626): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Searches_Top->_prepareCollection()
#12 /vagrant/www.mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(632): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareGrid()
#13 /vagrant/www.mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(862): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_beforeToHtml()
#14 /vagrant/www.mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 /vagrant/www.mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('topSearches', true)
#16 /vagrant/www.mysite.com/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/dashboard/index.phtml(113): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('topSearches')
#17 /vagrant/www.mysite.com/public_html/var/ait_rewrite/Mage_Core_Block_Template.php(412): include('/vagrant/www.sc...')
#18 /vagrant/www.mysite.com/public_html/var/ait_rewrite/Mage_Core_Block_Template.php(274): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#19 /vagrant/www.mysite.com/public_html/var/ait_rewrite/Mage_Core_Block_Template.php(288): Aitoc_Aitsys_Model_Rewriter_Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#20 /vagrant/www.mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Aitoc_Aitsys_Model_Rewriter_Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#21 /vagrant/www.mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#22 /vagrant/www.mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#23 /vagrant/www.mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#24 /vagrant/www.mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#25 /vagrant/www.mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#26 /vagrant/www.mysite.com/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(74): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#27 /vagrant/www.mysite.com/public_html/var/ait_rewrite/Mage_Core_Block_Template.php(412): include('/vagrant/www.sc...')
#28 /vagrant/www.mysite.com/public_html/var/ait_rewrite/Mage_Core_Block_Template.php(274): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#29 /vagrant/www.mysite.com/public_html/var/ait_rewrite/Mage_Core_Block_Template.php(288): Aitoc_Aitsys_Model_Rewriter_Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#30 /vagrant/www.mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Aitoc_Aitsys_Model_Rewriter_Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#31 /vagrant/www.mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#32 /vagrant/www.mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#33 /vagrant/www.mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#34 /vagrant/www.mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php(43): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#35 /vagrant/www.mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Adminhtml_DashboardController->indexAction()
#36 /vagrant/www.mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#37 /vagrant/www.mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#38 /vagrant/www.mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#39 /vagrant/www.mysite.com/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#40 /vagrant/www.mysite.com/public_html/index.php(88): Mage::run('', 'store')
#41 {main}
```

Comment: give us some /var/log data if you want to be helped, because this is not explicit at all

Comment: Are you running MySQL on the same box?

Answer (score 0):

I faced with problem like this and I can say that in my situation the /tmp partition run out of space and the query file couldn't be created. Please, check your /tmp directory.